# C++ program stop (freeze, no error, no exit) after a number of print (cout)

Tags: c#, c++, stdin, freeze, cout

I have this code to test the Ackermann function, I call it program **P1**. In the ackerman(int m, int n).
My purpose is, if  OUT haven't been defined, the program will run and just print the result after it completed. If OUT defined, the program will print "xxx" every "loop", and wait for a char input from stdin. I have an external process to read the output of **P1**, catch the "xxx" string (to do something) and write back a char to **P1**, so than it can continue.
if I compile without define OUT, and run P1 standalone, the code can run completely, and print out ack(3,6) = SomeValue, but if I enable OUT, and run the external process with P1, P1 can receive the char for a while, and "pause" suddenly, no crash, no error, no exit. I used c variable to count the times before P1 stopped, this is not a fixed number (3813, 3951, 3804,....). The external process is writed in C#, and was tested very well. I used it for many case but in this ackermann function, its stopped. Why it doesn't stop in the first loop, but in a pretty large number of loops? Is there any relation between the printing with the stopping?

**P1**:

```
int MAX = 99999;
class stack {
private:
    int num[99999];
    int size;
public:
    stack() {
        size = 0;
    }
    void push(long x) {
        if(size < MAX)
            num[++size] = x;
        else {
            cout<<"Full Stack"<<endl;
            return;
        }
    }
    int pop() {
        if(size==0) {
            cout<<"Out of stack memory"<<endl;
            return -1;
        } 
        return num[size--];
    }
    bool isEmpty() {
        if(size == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};

int ackman(int m,int n)
{
    stack v;
    v.push(m);
    int c = 0;
    while(!v.isEmpty()) {
        m = v.pop();
        if(m==0 ||n==0)
            n+= m+1;
        else {
            v.push(--m);
            v.push(++m);
            n--;
        }
        c++;

#ifdef OUT
        printf("c is %d\n",c );
        cout << endl;
        //flush(stdin);
        //flush(stdout);
        cout << "xxx" << endl;
        getchar(); 
        //sleep(200);
#endif
    }
    return n;
}

void ack() 
{
    int m = 3, n = 6;
#ifdef DEMO
    m = 3;
    n = 4;
#endif
    try{
        int k = ackman(m,n);
        printf("Ack %d , %d = %d\n",m,n,k );
    }catch(...){
        cout << "Co loi khi ack";
    }
}

//just example
int main(){
 ack();
return 0;
}
```

**External process**

```
static List<BenchMemory> benchMemory(String exeName, String caseName)
            {
                int count = 0;
                Console.Title = "Bench memory: " + exeName + " case: "+caseName;
                Console.WriteLine("Exe: {0}, case: {1}", exeName, caseName);
                using (Process process = new Process())
                {
                    /* Create the start info object */
                    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                    startInfo.FileName = exeName + ".exe";
                    startInfo.Arguments = caseName;
                    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                    List<BenchMemory> listMemResult = new List<BenchMemory>();
                    #region handler
                    DataReceivedEventHandler outDataHandler = (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
                    {
                        if (e.Data != null)
                        {
                            count++;
                            Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
                            if (!process.HasExited && e.Data != null && e.Data.ToLower().Equals("xxx"))
                            {
                                var bMem = getProcessMemory(process, exeName, caseName);
                                listMemResult.Add(bMem);
                                process.StandardInput.WriteLine("k");
                            }


                        }
                    };
                    #endregion
                    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                    process.OutputDataReceived += outDataHandler;
                    process.Start();
                    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                    process.WaitForExit();
                    var topPeak = listMemResult.Take(10).ToList();
                    process.Refresh();
                    return topPeak;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Are you using C# or C++?  Different languages.

Comment: When you used the debugger and single stepped through your program, which statement is causing the issue?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, The P1 is C++, the external process is C#, this is a bit annoying. But they are both Console App. Cause the program stop at a large number of iteration, I use print out method to find the problem line. The program run many round with "c is k", "c is k",... and stop after printed "c is ". Seem like the P1 could not receive anymore content from the external process and it stop because getchar(). I call P1 inside the external process so I can't manual press a key to pass the getchar(). I guess this is because I using fixed array for Stack, some kind of over array limit

Comment: Sure, you won't like getchar().  Consider passing a command line argument to your C program, like "/nopause", so you avoid calling it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `fflush(stdin);` in your C++ program should do the trick (a snippet of modified code bellow):

```
#ifdef OUT
        printf("c is %d\n",c );
        cout << endl;
        cout << "xxx" << endl;
        fflush(stdin); // note
        getchar();
#endif
```

For debugging purposes I also slightly modified your C# code, but nothing worth looking at:

```
DataReceivedEventHandler outDataHandler = (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
{
    if (e.Data != null)
    {
        var senderProcess = sender as Process;

        if(sender == null)
            Console.Write("Sender == NULL?");

        if(senderProcess.HasExited)
            Console.WriteLine("Exited");

        count++;
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);

        // e.Data != null redundant check, already everything wrapped in if(e.Data != null)
        if (e.Data.Trim().ToLower().Equals("xxx"))
        {
            senderProcess.StandardInput.Write("k");
            Console.WriteLine("Pass");
        }
    }
};
```

The number I got in my case was always 2047 for the first time, after replacing `WriteLine` with `Write` (`WriteLine` prints two characters, note the `\n`), I got to 4095. Power of 2 again (add +1)? Buffer? Checking with debugger `StandardOutput` you'll notice that indeed there are 4096 characters in the output buffer. Also, if setting a breakpoint to `Write`, you'll notice that after 4095 it'll get stuck in there (use conditional breakpoints to ease your life) and never get to `Console.WriteLine("Pass")`.

`StandardOutput.Flush` didn't really solve the problem (also couldn't find in the docs why) and also `getchar` doesn't clear it if I recall correctly.

Adding `fflush(stdin)` to C++ program clears it making space for C# to continue writing in it.